# multiple stores (sId), multiple products(pId) different prices. how do I design an efficient database

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, database-schema

Right now, I am designing the database, as such I don't have any code. I am looking to use sql server, asp.net if that is relevant. 
I have a big number of stores and a big number of products too, both in some thousands. For the same pId, prices may vary by sId. I would build it like this:
1. one "store" table containing fields (sId, name, location), 
2. one "products" table containing fields (pId, name size, category, sub-category) and 
3. "max(sId)" number of price tables containing fields (pId, mrp, availability). 
where max(sId) is the total number of stores.
I would rather not make "max(pId)" number of tables containing fields (sId, mrp, availability) as I need to provide a UI to each store so that they can update the details about product prices and availability at their respective stores. I also need to display some products of a particular store but I never need to display some stores for any specific product. That is, search for stores by product is not required, but listing of products by store would be required.
Is this a good way or can I do better?

Comment: Ugh - `sid, pid` - do you really think you save a ton of productivity to not type out `StoreID, ProductID`? Is all that extra time you gain from saving a few keystrokes then poured back into explaining the data model to everyone who sees it?

Comment: @aaron nice point, mentioned rudely. I was thinking deeply of the problem and had the urge to put it on the forum fast. Sure I will andhere to it. Design principles, naming conventions, casing, commenting, proper coding standards occupy a significant part in my professional life and have my respect. This young graduate will keep it in mind to not commit such mistakes again.

Comment: You came here for help, right? It's an all-too common wrong approach with the same excuses every time. Hard to suddenly assume you're the one exception to the rule, sorry. Suggest some thicker skin if you're going to post to sites like this - take constructive criticism or ignore comments.

Comment: Why don't you focus on maybe leaving a nice comment to the person who put a lot of work into answering, instead of spending all your energy on a comment that I don't really care if you take the advice or not? That's why it's a comment : to mention in passing, not to solve your overarching issue.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be on the right track and I will offer some recommendations. Although there is no requirement to display some stores for any specific products, you should always think about how the requirements will change and how your system can handle that. Build your system so that you can answer questions like these easily - *What stores have product ABC priced under $3/piece?*

Store table should contain, as you mentioned, information about stores. Take Aaron Bertrand's comment seriously. Name the fields in a way that the next developer can read and figure out what it is. User StoreID instead of sID.

```
StoreID    StoreName       ...other fields
-------    --------------
1          North Chicago
2          East Los Angeles
```

Product table should contain information about products. It would be better to store category and sub-category into a different table.

```
ProductID  ProductName     ...other fields
---------  --------------
1          Bread
2          Soap
```

Categories can be located in its own table with hierarchal structure. See [Hierarchal Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx) and how to use [hierarchyid data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677213.aspx). This may help in finding out the depth of each top level category and help management decide if they are going overboard with categorization and making life miserable for everybody, including themselves unknowingly.

Many-to-many ProductCategory table can link products to categories. Also keep a history table. When a product's category is changed, keep track of what it was and what it is set to. It may help in answering questions such as - *How many products were moved from Agriculture to Construction category in the last 6 months?*

Many-to-many StoreProductPrice can bring together store and product and a price can be defined there. Also remember - prices may differ by customers also. Some customers may get discounts at a certain level. Although this may be too much to discuss here, it should be kept in the back of the mind in case a requirement to support customer discount structure comes up.

```
StoreProductID  StoreID  ProductID  Price
--------------  -------  ---------  -----
1               1        1          $4.00
2               1        2          $1.00
3               2        1          $4.05
4               2        2          $1.02
```

Availability of the product should be done through the inventory management database table(s). For example, you may have a master table of `Warehouse` and master table of `Location`. Bringing them together would be `WearhouseLocation` table. A `WarehouseProduct` table may bring together warehouse, product and units available.

Alternatively, your production or procurement facility might be dumping data into `ProcuredProduct` table. Your manufacturing unit might be putting locks on a subset of products while building something out of it. Your sales unit might be putting locks on a subset of products they are trying to sell. In other words, your products may be continually get allocated. You may run queries to find out availability of a certain product and that can be a little taxing. During any such allocation, the number of available units can be updated in a single table (which contains calculated available products that you can comfortably rely on).

So...depending on your customer's needs, the system you are building can get fairly complicated. I am recommending that you think about these things and keep your database structure flexible to anticipated changes. Normalization is a good thing, and de-normalization has its place also. Use them wisely.